# How i could cut the last 7 second of my video with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I captured a video from my camera, but I don't know exactly how long it is. I want to use `ffmpeg` to keep and cut only the last 7 seconds of the video. Is this possible?

I tried the command:

```
ffmpeg -t 00:00:07 -i input.avi -vcodec copy newfile.avi
```

but it only skips the first 7 seconds of the video, and displays the video flipped.

Comment: I wonder why it shows the video flipped. But to know the duration of the video use the command `ffmpeg -i input.avi` without output file name. That will show duration. Then you can use `duration - 7` to use for the `-ss` flag. Provide the complete console output here.

Comment: I know that but i am trying to use ffmpeg from my C# code so i am trying to do it without know the duration of video. I just want to cut the last 7 seconds

Comment: I'm not at all learned about C# but why can't you query the duration from C#- ffmpeg/ffprobe (check the modules which provide duration in the code) and then pass the information back?

Answer (score 24):

Use the `-sseof` (seek relative to End of File) option.

Say you want to keep the last 7 seconds, you can use:

```
ffmpeg -sseof -7 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

See the [documentation here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).

*Note: This answer was posted in 2014 when this option did not exist. It was only added in 2015 — answer updated since.*

Answer (score 12):

Three different scenarios. I added the first two for clarification.

#### 1 - Want to keep only the last N seconds of a video

**instead of [-ss #] use [-sseof -#]** 
Example: -sseof -7

```
$ ffmpeg -sseof -7 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

Keeps the last 7 seconds of the video and discards the rest

#### 2 - Want to delete the last N seconds of a video and keep the rest. (Manually enter duration)

This option requires manual entry of end time (for automatic, see #3)
**Use -ss and -t (duration from start point) or -to (specific timestamp)**
You'll need to calculate the end time manually for this option.
Examples:

```
$ ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 01:32:00 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4;
```

Keeps the video from timestamp 00:00:00 to timestamp 01:32:00

```
$ ffmpeg -ss 00:00:04 -t 01:00:00 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4;
```

Keeps the video from timestamp 00:00:04 to timestamp 01:00:04
1 hour long video.

#### 3 - Want to delete the last N seconds of a video and keep the rest. (Auto-detect duration of file)

You'll need to use both `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe`, but it can all be done in terminal, with very little code.
The only way to cut off seconds based on the end time is to get the end time. I do batch processing of videos with varied lengths, so manually looking up and inputting each duration was out of the question. I needed to automatically access the duration value and pass it to ffmpeg.

**The Magic Formula:**

```
duration=`ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of csv=p=0 input.mp4`
duration=`bc $duration - seconds`
```

Example:

```
$ duration=`ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of csv=p=0 input.mp4`
$ duration=`bc $duration - 7`
$ ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to $duration -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

Removes the last 7 seconds of the video.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a bash script for convenience:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Arguments
FILE_RAW=$1
TRIM_EOF_DURATION=${2:-1.0} # Default is 1.0 second trimmed from EOF

# Prepare variables
BASE_PATH=$(dirname $(readlink -f $FILE_RAW))
FILENAME_EXT="$(basename "${FILE_RAW}")"
FILENAME_ONLY="${FILENAME_EXT%.*}"
EXT_ONLY="${FILENAME_EXT#*.}" # Or hardcode it like "mp4"
FILENAME_ONLY_PATH="${BASE_PATH}/${FILENAME_ONLY}"

# Trim EOF duration
INPUT_DURATION=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "${FILENAME_ONLY_PATH}.${EXT_ONLY}")
OUTPUT_DURATION=$(bc <<< "$INPUT_DURATION"-"$TRIM_EOF_DURATION")
ffmpeg -i "${FILENAME_ONLY_PATH}.${EXT_ONLY}" -map 0 -c copy -t "$OUTPUT_DURATION" "${FILENAME_ONLY_PATH}_Trim_${TRIM_EOF_DURATION}.${EXT_ONLY}"
```

**Note:** Make script executable: `chmod +x trim_video.sh`

**Usage** (Output File: `<PATH_TO_INPUT_VIDEO>_Trim_<TRIM_EOF_DURATION>.mp4`)

```
. <PATH_TO_THIS_SCRIPT>/trim_video.sh <PATH_TO_INPUT_VIDEO> <OPTIONAL_TRIM_EOF_DURATION>
```

**Example:** Trim 7.0 seconds from EOF (Output: `~/Videos/input_video_Trim_7.0.mp4`)

```
. ~/trim_video.sh ~/Videos/input_video.mp4 7.0
```

Comment: This works, thanks!